# SSRS iif condition failing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

My requirement -  If condition satisfy then ID column should be blue else black

Blue color = type="NY" and isact=true and eqe=true

Blue color = type="CAL" and isact=true

black color = type="NY" and isact=false and eqe=false

black color = type="NY" and isact=false and eqe=true

black color = type="NY" and isact=true and eqe=false

black color = type="CAL" and isact=false

```
=IIf(Fields!IsAct.Value = True,
     IIf(Fields!EQE.Value = True,
         IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "NY",  "Blue","Black"),"Black"), "Black")
  or 
  IIf(Fields!IsAct.Value = False,
     IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "CAL",  "Black","Blue"), "Black")
```

I have this logic in font ID column. If I run above individually then its working but if i combine its not working. Any help is really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

This is looking very complex and I think there's a cleaner way to do this with a `SWITCH` statement.  I believe the following expression should work well.

```
=SWITCH(
        Fields!Type.Value = "NY" AND Fields!IsAct.Value AND Fields!EQE.Value, "Blue",
        Fields!Type.Value = "CAL" AND Fields!IsAct.Value, "Blue",
        Fields!Type.Value = "CAL" AND NOT Fields!IsAct.Value, "Black",
        Fields!Type.Value = "NY" AND NOT Fields!IsAct.Value AND NOT Fields!EQE.Value, "Black",
        Fields!Type.Value = "NY" AND NOT Fields!IsAct.Value AND Fields!EQE.Value, "Black",
        Fields!Type.Value = "NY" AND Fields!IsAct.Value AND NOT Fields!EQE.Value, "Black",
        True, "Black")
```

So I think that expression handles all of the cases you provided, but if I'm reading correctly, you really only have 2 conditions that set the color to blue, otherwise it is black.  So the following should work just as well.

```
= IIF((Fields!Type.Value = "NY" AND Fields!IsAct.Value AND Fields!EQE.Value) 
        OR (Fields!Type.Value = "CAL" AND Fields!IsAct.Value), "Blue", "Black")
```

Comment: I tried both above. It is working for 1st condition but not after "Or". It is showing blue even Fields!Type.Value = "CAL" and Fields!IsAct.Value=false.

Comment: In your question, you have `Blue color = type="CAL" and isact=true` and `Blue color = type="CAL" and isact=false`.  I'm guessing you made some typo here?  This says that it's blue when `type = "CAL"` regardless of whether `IsAct` is true or false. Please clarify which condition should be blue and I can modify my answer.

Comment: sorry my bad...I put wrong statement. I have modified main statement now.